# API del Servicio de Normalización de Datos Geográficos de Argentina no devuelve los datos requeridos

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy intentando usar esa api del titulo para practicar, ultimamente devolvia este mensaje

```
{
  "message": "API rate limit exceeded"
}
```

Lo que me llamo la atencion, en un principio pense que tenia algo mal en el codigo, utilizo react, pero si trato de acceder a esa url desde el navegador siempre devuelve eso. Hay varias urls mas, pero todas devuelven ese mensaje. Tiene para buscar por provincia, localidad, departamento. Mi primera pregunta seria porque devuelve eso la api, segunda consulta si conocen algo similar para argentina o cualquier pais. He visto que hasta hace un tiempo habia una api en mexico que era de uso gratuito y tenia la funcion de poder brindar tu lugar de residencia, pero ahora es de pago, si pueden comentarme me ayudaria, gracias.

Comment: Yo la estoy usando para llenar un select con las provincias y dependiendo de la provincia que elijas lleno otro con las localidades de dicha provincia y me funciona. De hecho acabo d probar algunos endpoints desde el cel y cargan ok

Comment: Hola, @Hernan Garcia, no sé yo estoy probando en varios navegadores, y nada o sea, a veces si, y a veces no, y directamente copiando y pegando la url hablo, es con la unica api que me pasa esto. Justamente la necesitaba para lo mismo que estas haciendo.

Comment: Con estas url me funciona siempre bien, de hecho lo acabo de probar. provincias: https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/provincias?&campos=id,nombre   Y por ejemplo las localidades de catamarca: https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/municipios?provincia=catamarca&campos=id,nombre&max=150

Comment: Mirad las cabeceras de la respuesta. Hay un límite establecido (diario, horario, por minutos y por segundos). Si hacéis la prueba con dos peticiones consecutivas veréis cómo van cambiando esos límites dentro del día, hora o minuto. Y como se indica en las Condiciones de uso de la API (https://datosgobar.github.io/georef-ar-api/terms/) los organismos públicos (no sé si otros también si se les pide por correo electrónico) pueden hacer consultas con identificación para aumentar esos límites.